# opencv pca Is it possible to change the reference point(center point) when extracting eigenvectors? I don't want to center point

Tags: opencv, pca

In the opencv pca function, can I extract the eigenvector by grabbing the starting point I want, not based on the center point? For example min (x, y) point in 2d coordinates.

opencv

Introduction to Principal Component Analysis (PCA) (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d1/dee/tutorial_introduction_to_pca.html)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIf10.png)

I want the reference point to be min(x, y) or max(x, y) of the data.

Comment: the center point in the sample code is only used for visualization (as a base for the axes). it is entirely irrelevant for the pca calculation. you're free to choose any point you like.

Comment: "can I extract the eigenvector by grabbing the starting point"  -- seems you misread something. again, there is no "starting point"